# Postgresql - Insert when select return something

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, select-case

Is it possible to run select query, check if row exist and then insert some values? I would like to do that in one query. I think about SELECT .. CASE .. THEN, for example:

```
SELECT user_id, CASE when user_id > 0 then (INSERT INTO another_table ...) ELSE return 0 END 
FROM users WHERE user_id = 10
```

Now I'm able to do that with 2 queries, first do SELECT and second INSERT values (if first query return something).

Thanks!

Comment: `insert.. select vlaues where exists (your select qry)` ?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general the construct is:

```
INSERT INTO another_table 
SELECT value1,value2..etc
where exists (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = 10)
```

or in this particular case:

```
INSERT INTO another_table 
SELECT value1,value2..etc
FROM users WHERE user_id = 10
```

If no such user, no rows will be selected and so inserted

Comment: You are a boss! Thanks.